# Python: proper way to check if arguments are valid and set default if none of them is valid

Tags: python, validation, error-handling, initialization, args

I'm new to objective programming in python and I can't figure out how to give variable number of arguments to class constructor, check if they are on on a specific list of available arguments and accept only those valid ones. If none of them is valid I need to set a default argument. I suppose I can make a loop and check each and every one of arguments given in the loop, but I hope there is more elegant way to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
class Sandbox():
def __init__(is_female, *args):
    d=dict(F="female", M="male")
    if is_female in d:
        self.sex=d[is_female]
    if args not in ["velociraptor", "brontozaur", "triceratops"]:
        self.dinozaur="velociraptor"
    else:
        print " $ "
```

Comment: `is_female` is misleading name, it suggests that it should contain `True` for females and `False` for males, I'd change it's name to `sex`.

Comment: Hint: that's not how you use `in` in your `if args not in`... try: `2 in [1, 2, 3]`, `(2,) in [1, 2, 3]`. Maybe you mean `if not set(args).issubset({"velociraptor", "brontozaur", "triceratops"})`

Comment: This is what I did:       `class Sandbox():
    def __init__(sex, *args):
        d=dict(F="female", M="male")
        if is_fimejl in d:
            self.sex=d[sex]
        z=[]
        z.append(next((a for a in args if a in ["welociraptor", "brontozaur", "triceratops"]), None))
        if len(z)==0:
            z.append("welociraptor")`

Comment: You need to take `self` as first parameter of `__init__`.